# What to do when an edit to a dated post duplicates existing answer?

Tags: discussion, edits, duplicate-answers

I have had this happen to me and seen it happen to others multiple times and I am wonder what the appropriate response (if any) would be to the following scenario:

- Some answer will have posted code to answer a users question. In many cases this answer is several years old.
- Since then updates to the language or relevant packages have been made such that different code is now preferred. In this scenario, I post a new answer with a more up-to-date solution.
- Some time after that the old poster makes an edit which essentially creates a duplicate answer of my post.

Should I delete my post? Or is the onus on the editor to make sure they aren't duplicating an already existing answer?

Many times these old answers have a lot of upvotes so it would take a newer answer some time to "rise to the top" and since their post has the old solution in addition to the new one there is more information for posterity's sake.

Comment: "*so it would take a newer answer some time to "rise to the top"*" that happens so rarely as to be almost equivalent to "never". The trending sort could help but also not necessarily. I've seen it show newly posted duplicate (or just bad) answers higher just because they have 1-3 upvotes while a decade old, three digit scored answer which is still the "state-of-the-art" solution is below those.

Answer (score 6):

Option 3: nothing is wrong so nothing needs to be done and nobody needs to rethink their actions.

Let me rewrite your bullet list from a different perspective.

- You wrote a new answer to add value.
- Someone else at a later date improved their own answer to add value.

I mean if we're going to be making assumptions, then let's assume the best. Both actions are exactly what we want people to do. And sometimes you end up with a less than ideal situation like this. With two good answers that through circumstance happen to be pretty much the same. I think we'll live, don't you?

You CAN delete your answer. I will never tell you that you SHOULD. I guess if you're really strict about wanting the repository to be clean... you could make that decision to delete yours. But then when the other person decides to rollback their changes at some later date, are you going to undelete your answer again?

Comment: FWIW, if I came across this situation later on as a third party, I would absolutely custom-flag the new answer as a duplicate... nothing personal and not that the new answer author did anything wrong, but duplication is clutter and Stack Overflow is about the opposite of that.